# Update or create rows database. Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, for-loop, eloquent

I have a little problem with creating a new record in the database. I need to create or update records in the skills table. Request from the user is an array. I use a loop for retrieving data from requests. When I submit the form, the skills array show empty. How can I solve this problem?

Thanks, Advance

```
    $skills = [];
    
   for ($i = 0;$i < count($validated['skills_name']);$i++)
   {
    
          $data = [
                   'name' => $validated['skills_name'][$i], 
                   'rate' => $validated['skills_rate'][$i]
                  ];
    
          $skills[] = $data;                  
    }
    
    Skill::updateOrCreate(['profile_key' => Auth::user()->profile->key],$skills);
```

Answer (score 0):

in PHP, you can create an empty array like this

```
$skills = array();
```

and then if you want to push data to the array, you can simply use this code

```
array_push($skills , $data);
```

Comment: The problem located here. `Skill::updateOrCreate(['profile_key' => Auth::user()->profile->key],{{------$skills is empty------}}$skills);`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your supports. I solved the problem.

```
for ($i=0; $i <count($validated['skills_name']) ; $i++) 
{ 
     $skill = new Skill();
     $skill->profile_key = Auth::user()->profile->key;
     $skill->name = $validated['skills_name'][$i];
     $skill->rate = $validated['skills_rate'][$i];
     $skill->save();                          
}
```